# Add the subtracted value from previous user value in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I have run into an issue where i am adding the point for a user with the previous point already stored in the table via **laravel**. Now I have an issue where i need to loop all the points of a specific user and I need to add in a new column for each entry the difference between the old previous point and the current point.

[image: 1]

From the table i have first entry point is 1 , second entry point is 11, third is 21 and 4th is 22. Here what I need is, I need to loop all these data and for the first record i need to add the difference as 1 in new column and for second the difference between 1st and 2nd row are 10 and for 3rd the difference between 2nd and 3rd are again 10 and for 4th record th diff between the 3rd and 4th are 1.

Please someone provide me with a function which will help me to update new column with the difference in points based on previous and the current point

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using model
You can try this.

```
// $id is equal to user_id
function difference($id) {
    // First get all your data
    $data = YourModel::where('user_id', $id)->get();

    // Loop all your data
    foreach($data as $d) {

        //get previous data
        $last = YourModel::where('user_id',$id)->where('created_at', '<', $d->created_at)->first();

        // if null then return zero else get the point
        $last = isset($last) ? $last->points : 0;

        // get the difference from the last
        $dif = $d->points - $last;

        // putting the difference to the data
        $d->difference = $dif;
        $d->save();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you...